# Transforming a plain-text file with Emacs to HTML. How to add closing tags?

Tags: html, emacs, lisp, elisp

I'm writing a function for Emacs to transform an auto-generated plain text file to HTML, but encountering a question...How to add closing tags (e.g. `</div>`)?

**(Note: Org-mode's build-in org-export is not what I want.)**

The plain text as input like this:

```
* 2012
** Jan
   balahbalah
   ...
** Feb
   balahbalah
   ...
* 2013
** Mar
   balahbalah
   ...
```

(I've written a function can copy the whole file to the another buffer and process "balahbalah".)

And the desired output is:

```html
<div class="year">
  <h2>2012</h2>
  <div class="month">
    <h3>Jan</h3>
    balahbalah
    ....
  </div>
  <div class="month">
    <h3>Feb</h3>
    balahbalah
    ....
  </div>
</div>

<div class="year">
  <h2>2013</h2>
  <div class="month">
    <h3>March</h3>
    balahbalah
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```

How should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, some fresh code:

```
(defun org-to-list ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((str
          (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) 
                                          (point-max)))
         (years-str (delete "" (split-string str "^* ")))
         (years 
          (mapcar 
           (lambda(x) 
             (when (string-match "^\\([0-9]+\\)\\([^\0]*\\)$" x)
               (list (match-string 1 x)
                     (mapcar 
                      (lambda (y)
                        (when (string-match 
                               "^\\([a-zA-Z]+\\)\\([^\0]*\\)$" y)
                          (cons (match-string 1 y)
                                (match-string 2 y))))
                      (delete 
                       "\n" 
                       (split-string (match-string 2 x) "^** "))))))
           years-str)))
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window 
     (get-buffer-create "*Generated HTML*"))
    (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
    (insert
     (mapconcat 
      (lambda(x) 
        (concat
         (format "<div class=\"year\">\n  <h2>%s</h2>\n" (car x))
         (mapconcat 
          (lambda(y)
            (concat
             (format 
              "  <div class=\"month\">\n    <h3>%s</h3>\n" (car y))
             (mapconcat 
              (lambda(z)(format "    %s" z))
              (delete "" (split-string (cdr y) "\n"))
              "\n")
             "\n  </div>"))
          (cadr x)
          "\n")
         "\n</div>\n"))
      years
      "\n"))))
```

You can run it with <kbd>M-x</kbd>. It creates a new buffer with contents like:

```
<div class="year">
  <h2>2012</h2>
  <div class="month">
    <h3>Jan</h3>
    spam
  </div>
  <div class="month">
    <h3>Feb</h3>
    and eggs!
  </div>
</div>

<div class="year">
  <h2>2013</h2>
  <div class="month">
    <h3>Mar</h3>
    spam spam?
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Emacs org-mode comes with a html-exporter.
Org-mode has its own info-file:

C-h i RET m Org Mode RET

See tag "Exporting"

Comment: That's not what I want at all. You can export a file and view its HTML code. The reason I use org-like input file is that it's convenient for Emacs to fold outline. However, the parts "balahbalah" are not org's format